# Can I ethically release videos containing results of employer's project for self-promotion?

Tags: professionalism, ethics

As an engineer, I'm wondering about the ethical issues related to posting videos showing the result of the projects I've worked on. Since the projects are basically funded by the company, I wonder if that would ethically be problematic.

The idea is to post a video containing only the **results** of the project on the web e.g. Youtube, LinkedIn, etc. Of course, the HOW's will not be disclosed since the company has invested in them. The intention behind the post isn't to promote the employer, but my engineering skills with hopes of my work getting exposure when it's unique.

Given the described context, are there any ethical limits crossed? Or are there any other problems that would rise as a result of posting it?

Comment: The legal angle is off-topic and I've removed that but really, why don't you just ask your employer? The standard answer to "Is it ethical to do X with Y?" is simply "Yes, with the permission of whoever owns/controls Y."

Comment: How is this different from listing accomplishments on your CV?

Comment: Talk to HR/marketing about permission, we can't answer this.  Voting to close

Comment: Changing some things to say ethical instead of legal doesn't change the fact that it's still a legal and policy question. Even if it didn't, "ethical limits" are purely opinion. Any other problems that would rise?  Yeah. Legal problems and possibly company policy.. That's why we can't really answer it. I'm all for editing to make on-topic but the core of this question has to do with IP, not ethics. Closing. Well, attempting to but gnat beat me to it.

Comment: @rath CV's can say lots of things and blow accomplishments out of proportions. Not to say that the video can't be manipulated, but it can provide an extra piece of supporting material.

Comment: My question is, why would listing things accomplishments on your CV be any different than narrating them over fancy graphics in a video, and therefore, why would it require the company's consent (as many answers indicate)? Then again I might've not understood what kind of video you intend to create.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I get your points. However, I'm eager to know about what's established as rules of thumb for such matters; there wouldn't be much point in having codes of conduct if ethical limits were "purely opinion," right? I understand, though, that the question is somewhat off-topic.

Comment: @rath I think I get the confusion. The video is not necessarily a narration with fancy graphics. It would actually show the result. If there were say, robots involved, you would see the robots performing what I would list in my CV as accomplishment. Having the result posted won't only be to prove that I have done it, but also to get exposure for my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely need to ask your company.  We have no idea because we have not seen your company handbook, employee handbook, or your employment contract.

Sidenote: The intent is pretty clear: you want other people besides your employer to notice you. Your employer probably will see through that and won't like you using your work for them to help you leverage an offer from someone else. Instead, proudly display your company's brand, show off the cool stuff the project can do, and show its impact on your vertical. This will be much more palatable to the company and the results will be two-fold: other companies will want you to come do that for them (this is the exposure you wanted) and your profile within your company will improve as well.  This puts you in a position to be wanted by others and wanted by your own company.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not do this without permission!**

Depending on your contract and location, this could be a legal issue as well as an ethical one. Even if you don't release the process, the results still belong to your company. This amounts to publicly releasing company information without company approval. In many places this would get you fired on the spot.

Now, by all means, you should certainly still ask and may even be granted permission. However, don't expect the answer to be yes, at least not without some oversight. Probably the best you can hope for is a promotional video for your company that you can point to and say "I did that".